# Are all odd natural numbers of form $\dfrac{n\cdot 2^{\alpha}-1}{3}$, where $n$ is also an odd natural number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While searching for patterns in odd natural numbers, I realised that if $k$ is an odd natural number then:

$$k=\frac{n \cdot 2^{\alpha}-1}{3},$$

where $n$ is an odd natural number and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$.

Even though I have arrived at this conjecture I cannot seem to think of a way to prove it. Can someone furnish the proof for the said conjecture or refer to any earlier stated proofs of this.

Comment: Take $k = 5$. Then $n = 7 > k$ and $\alpha = 1$. So, your conjecture is not, in general, ture.

Comment: @Aniruddha Deshmukh that counterexample isn't correct.

Comment: @ArthurVause: You are correct! I misread the negative sign.

Comment: That part of statement is not necessary to the conjecture, hence I have removed it in an edit.

Comment: Basically you want to write $3k + 1$ as $2^{\alpha}n$, for $n < k$. Will prime decomposition help?

Answer (score 4):

Any even number can be expressed as $n.2^\alpha$ where $n$ is odd and $\alpha\geq 1$ - just keep taking out factors of $2$ until what you have left is odd. So the statement is basically saying "if $k$ is odd then $3k+1$ is even", which is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

if 3 does not divide n, then there are multiples alphas that make n * 2 ^ alpha -1 divisible by 3.

If n mod 3 is 1, then alpha is even (any even number> = 2), and gives a valid k.

If n mod 3 is 2, then alpha is odd (any odd number> = 1), and gives a valid k.

If 3 divides n, then there is no alpha that gives a valid k.

n=1, alpha=8, k=85

n=1, alpha=6, k=21

n=17, alpha=1, k=11

n=17, alpha=3, k=45

...

The other sense, given k, finding alpha and n is trivial, and is related to how the number (3k + 1) is written in binary code.

The number of the last 0's is the alpha, and odd n is the result of removing those last 0's.

Example:

k=45

3k+1 = 136 (dec) = 10001000 (bin)

alpha = 3 (last 3 zeros)

n = 10001 (bin) = 17 (dec)

And every number, which in binary, ends in 1, is an odd number.